# Dispose MemoryStream when using with .Net Mail Attachment

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, memorystream, using-statement

I am using a MemoryStream to add attachments from binary that is stored in a DB.  My problem is that I want to properly dispose of the MemoryStream. This is easily done using a "using" statement, but when I have more than one attachment I don't know how to properly dispose of the multiple MemoryStreams.

Is there a good way to iterate over and attach the files, but yet at the same time properly dispose of the MemoryStreams that I am using to attach? When I tried to flush/close prior to using smtp.Send it through an error stating that the stream was already closed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The MailMessage.Dispose() method already disposes its attachments, you don't have to help.

Comment: @HansPassant This should be the answer. Way better than holding up a list of streams then disposing it all.

Comment: @HansPassant I just noticed that it is only applied with `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` and not with the deprecated `System.Web.Mail.MailMessage` which doesn't implement Idisposeable

Comment: Well, you figured out one reason why it was deprecated.  CDO is stone cold old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate the `MemoryStream`s and dispose them. Putting the disposing code in a `finally` block equals to `using` statement.

```
var list = new List<MemoryStream>(){new MemoryStream(), new MemoryStream()};

try
{
    //....
}
finally
{
    foreach (var x in list)
    {
        x.Dispose();
    }
}
```

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler.

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: THanks @gdoron I will take a look...appreciate the example

Comment: Why create a List? The Attachment class has access to the Stream with the Attachment class Property ContentStream. You can then dispose the stream first and then dispose your attachment in a finally block. See  MSDN [link]( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Mail.Attachment(v=vs.110).aspx) I chose to do this because not all my MailMessages have attachments and I don't know how many attachments to expect so I couldn't use the using statement. I suppose I could restructure all my code to accommodate a using, but this seemed simpler.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old post, but it turns out that disposing `MailMessage` or just enclosing it inside `using` statement is enough as when `MailMessage` is disposed all `AttachmentCollection` is also disposed and when `Attachment` is disposed, `Stream` is also disposed. Check out [ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailMessage.cs) for complete code.

```
using(MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
{
   // Add attachments without worring about disposing them
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
  using (var ms2 = new MemoryStream())
  {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @leppie...problem is I could have 1 to many attachments...I think the List of memorystreams might work

Comment: You can use `Container` for that perhaps.

Comment: What do you mean by `container`?

Comment: @gdoron: Actually, that wont work. I incorrectly thought the `Container` class allows one to add any `IDisposable`, but after looking it only take `IComponent`. :(