# RedirectToAction does not work

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

The RedirectToAction does not display the View.

```
    // Go populate and display PDF using XML file
    DoPDF(stXML); 
}
UpDateDropDown(model);
return RedirectToAction("ReportsSelection", "Reports");
```

Rendering Code:

```
private void DoPDF(String stXML)
{
    string filename = string.Concat(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ".pdf");
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(Request.MapPath(_NFCPage._NFReference.FM_NOFEAR_PDF)), null);
    // Create the iTextSharp document
    // Set the document to write to memory

    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfStamper ps = new PdfStamper(reader, memStream);
        // Populate the PDF with values in the XML file
        AcroFields af = ps.AcroFields;
        ParserXML(stXML, af);
        ps.FormFlattening = false;
        ps.Writer.CloseStream = false;
        ps.Close();
        byte[] buf = new byte[memStream.Position];
        memStream.Position = 0;
        memStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        // Set the appropriate ContentType
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
        // Get the physical path to the file
        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0};", filename));
        // Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();

        Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.GetBuffer());  //Comment out to work
        Response.End();                               //Comment out to work
    }
}
```

I have noticed that if I remove the last two lines in the DoPDF routine that it does display the view.

Answer (score 3):

Response.End() will cause the server to send the HTTP response.  Your browser at that point will consider the request completed and the redirect won't happen.  Can you provide more context on what you're trying to accomplish?  Then we can get a better idea of how to help you.

Comment: Once the PDF is rendered, I want to go to the Main Menu View. This the reason for the "RedirectToAction" request or is there another way to switch Views?

Comment: So do you want the PDF to render in a separate tab?  Where do you want the PDF to render?

Comment: The Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0};", filename)); will bring up the Open/Save/Cancel Box. If the operator selects "Open", the PDF renders to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: nvm, you have a `Response.End()` call there, that will end execution of the request and your redirect will obviously not work. If you're trying to *flush* the stream then you need to do `Response.Flush()` instead.

Comment: If I remove the Response.End(), the PDF does not render. Will doing a Reponse.Flush() and Response.Close() get it to render?

Comment: You might need to do the binary write on a single view, and provide a way for the user to go to the next page manually... I'm not entirely sure you can inject a file _and_ redirect afterward if you need to close the response.

Answer (score 1):

Don't handle files downloads in MVC, as you can see, it can cause problems...

```
return File(memStream, "Application/pdf", filename);
```

Will do everything for you.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file.aspx)

Comment: The return call returns an error if I place inside the using statement and if I place it outside then it can not find memStream. If I remove the using then the return call returns an error.

Comment: If I put the return File(memStream, "Application/pdf", filename); in place of theResponse.End(); the "return" is underlined in RED. If I put it ouside the Using statement, it can not find memStream.

Comment: @JohnDonaldson. so don't use the `using statement` it just `dispose`  the stream, you can do it yourself. take a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8982963/601179) answer about `using statement `

Comment: I tried not using the using statement and the return is then underlined in RED which is an error.  Is the File suppose to be highlighted. If so mabey I don't have the assembly for it included.